# Jquery calculation not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little piece of jQuery code which calculates the recipe ingredients as per given serving, but somewhere it's not working properly.

My code is like this:

```
Serving: <input type="text" name="serving" class="serving" value="5" /> persons
<input type="hidden" id="previousServing" value="5"/>

        <h3>ingredients</h3>
        <ul class="ingredients">
        <li class="ingredient">
        <span class="amount">1</span> cups
        <span class="name"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/ingredient/yogurt/">yogurt</a></span>
        </li>

        <li class="ingredient">
        <span class="amount">2</span> tbsp
        <span class="name"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/ingredient/yogurt/">chillies</a></span>
        </li>

        <li class="ingredient">
        <span class="amount">3</span> pieces
        <span class="name"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/ingredient/yogurt/">butter</a></span>
        </li>
        </ul>



$(function() {
  $('.serving').bind('keyup', function(event) {
    var previousValue = parseFloat($("#previousServing").val());
    var newValue = parseFloat($(event.target).val());
    if (previousValue && newValue) {
        $('.ingredient').each(function(index, elem) {
            var ingredientNow = $('.amount', elem);
            var oldIngredientAmount = ingredientNow.text();
            var newIngredientAmount = oldIngredientAmount * newValue / previousValue;
            ingredientNow.text(newIngredientAmount);
        });
        $('#previousServing').val(newValue);
    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vansimke/tLWpr/

issues:

1. change the serving to 1.5 and it will give unlimited decimal places
2. set the serving back to original (5), decimals wont disappear

Required: either no decimals or round to absolute two digit, i.e., 2.08 should be 2.00.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Problem:  Significant figures and rounding**

You need to times `newIngredientAmount` to get a number of sigfigs then use `Math.round` to round it to the nearest integer.   Then divide the result by the number you multiplied by earlier

http://jsfiddle.net/vQbQ6/12/

Added this line

```
newIngredientAmount = Math.round(newIngredientAmount * 100) / 100;
```

To create

```
$(function() {
  $('.serving').bind('keyup', function(event) {
    var previousValue = parseFloat($("#previousServing").val());
    var newValue = parseFloat($(event.target).val());
    if (previousValue && newValue) {
        $('.ingredient').each(function(index, elem) {
            var ingredientNow = $('.amount', elem);
            var oldIngredientAmount = ingredientNow.text();
            var newIngredientAmount = oldIngredientAmount * newValue / previousValue;
            newIngredientAmount = Math.round(newIngredientAmount * 100) / 100; 
            ingredientNow.text(newIngredientAmount);
        });
        $('#previousServing').val(newValue);
    }
});
```

**Second Problem: Jquery .data(key, value) solution**

The problem you have with the decimal hanging around is a problem due to rounding and `oldIngredientAmount * newValue / previousValue` because some of these values could have been rounded.  It seems to me that this is a bad way going about calulating the ingredient amount.  You should instead by basing the math off of the inital ingredient ratios instead of the rounded derived numbers you calculate.  You could use jquery `.data()` to record the inital values in the amount spans and do math off those numbers each time.

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Fiddler with `.data()` to preserve the initial ratio and use that in the math

http://jsfiddle.net/vQbQ6/14/

```
$(function() {
    $('.ingredient').each(function(index, elem){
        $this = $(this);
        $this.data('init', parseFloat($this.text()));
    });

    $('#previousServing').data('init', parseFloat($('#previousServing').val()));

    $('.serving').bind('keyup', function(event) {
        var previousValue = $("#previousServing").data('init');
        var newValue = parseFloat($(event.target).val());
        if (previousValue && newValue) {
            $('.ingredient').each(function(index, elem) {
                var ingredientNow = $('.amount', elem);
                var initIngredientAmount = $(this).data('init');
                var newIngredientAmount = initIngredientAmount * newValue / previousValue;
                newIngredientAmount = Math.round(newIngredientAmount * 100) / 100; 
                ingredientNow.text(newIngredientAmount);
            });
            $('#previousServing').val(newValue);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it seems working once i added your given line, regarding the 2nd prob and since i am not good at jQ, would you spare some time to demonstrate an example; please. if required, i can make appropriate changes in my html code

Comment: perfect and thank you, only one more issue, when i use 1/4 or 3/4 it wont calculate properly? but thanks a million for providing a solid base

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round(newIngredientAmount)` will round the number for you.

However, I just played around with your code. I don't think it's reliable for you to use the previously calculated value, especially if you're rounding it. That will mess up all your ingredient ratios.

This is what I would do

```
Serving: <input type="text" name="serving" class="serving" value="5" /> persons
<input type="hidden" id="defaultServing" value="5"/>

            <h3>ingredients</h3>
            <ul class="ingredients">
            <li class="ingredient">
            <span class="amount" defaultAmount="1">1</span> cups
            <span class="name"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/ingredient/yogurt/">yogurt</a></span> 
            </li>

            <li class="ingredient">
            <span class="amount" defaultAmount="2">2</span> tbsp
            <span class="name"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/ingredient/yogurt/">chillies</a></span> 
            </li>

            <li class="ingredient">
            <span class="amount" defaultAmount="3">3</span> pieces
            <span class="name"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/ingredient/yogurt/">butter</a></span> 
            </li>
            </ul>
```

​

```
$(function() {
    $('.serving').bind('keyup', function(event) {
        var previousValue = parseFloat($("#defaultServing").val());
        var newValue = parseFloat($(event.target).val());
        if (previousValue && newValue) {
            $('.ingredient').each(function(index, elem) {
                var ingredientNow = $('.amount', elem);
                var oldIngredientAmount = ingredientNow.attr("defaultAmount");
                var newIngredientAmount = oldIngredientAmount * newValue / previousValue;
                // no decimal places
                // ingredientNow.text(Math.round(newIngredientAmount));
                // two decimal places
                ingredientNow.text(Math.round(newIngredientAmount*100)/100);
            });

        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: this seems a good option, my only concern is, will it validate html?

Comment: @user1305063 it won't. If you want it to, you can instead put it in a hidden input